# How to have multiple select attributes of an entity in DHIS2 tracker?

Tags: dhis2

In DHIS2 tracker, during the registration of an entity, how can I make the user able to select multiple options of an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as allowing multiple selection per attributes / data elements will complicate analysis. The recommended approach is to break the attribute into multiple ones so that each gets single selection.